# How to play a 16-bit WAV in raspberry pi 3 b+ with PWM?

Tags: gpio

I have a 16-bit WAV file, the header of the file as below:

```
WAV header Information:
RIFF            : RIFF
Chunk Size      : 5719002
Format          : WAVE

Sub-Chunk 1 Information:
Sub-Chunk 1 ID  : fmt 
Sub-Chunk Size  : 16
Audio Format    : 1 (PCM = 1)
Channels        : 1 (MONO = 1, STERIO = 2)
Sampling Rate   : 250000 Hz
Byte Rate       : 500000 (500000)
block Alignment : 2 (2)
Bits Per Sample : 16 bits

Sub-Chunk 2 Information:
Sub-Chunk 2 ID  : data
Sub-Chunk Size  : 5718016
```

I am gonna develop a program that play it in my pi 3 b+ with PWM with wiringPi api. I read the data from the WAV file, and output it by the api `void pwmWrite (int pin, int value)`, the value was set to the value from the WAV file data. But i got a noise not a music.

My question is :

In the api `pwmSetRange (unsigned int range)` the type of `range` is `unsigned int`, and in `void pwmWrite (int pin, int value)`, the type of range is `int`, and the range of `value` is `0-1024` from the reference.

But my WAV file is 16-bit, the range is —32768-32767, so i am confused to set the range and value in those api.

Looking forward to receive answers.